# JQuery toggle div´s with different Buttons and Show/Hide by click active one

Tags: jquery, html, button, jquery-animate, toggle

I have three buttons (inactive on load).
When i click a button the div shows.
When i click the second button first hide, second show...

HTML

```
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="button" data-rel="#a" href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a class="button" data-rel="#b" href="#">B</a></li>
                        <li><a class="button" data-rel="#c" href="#">C</a></li>
                    </ul> 

                    <div class="flr-inner">
                        <div id="a" class="container hide">
                          AAA
                        </div>
                        <div id="b" class="container hide">
                          BBB
                        </div>
                        <div id="c" class="container hide">
                          CCC
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQuery

```
                        // set content on click
                        $('.button').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            setContent($(this));
                        });

                        // set content on load
                        $('.button.active').length && setContent($('.button.active'));

                        function setContent($el) {
                            $('.button').removeClass('active');
                            $('.container').animate({
                                height: "hide",
                                opacity: "hide"
                            }, "fast");;

                            $el.addClass('active');
                            $($el.data('rel')).animate({
                                height: "show",
                                opacity: "show"
                            }, "slow");;
                        }
```

But how can i toggle the active div, so that no one is visible?
And how to do (fadeout. stop. fadein.) actually it´s doing everything parallel.

Answer (score 0):

**queue** option controls wait or not end of action 

    `function setContent(el){
        $('.button').removeClass('active');
        $('.container').fadeOut({queue: true, speed: "fast"});
        el.addClass('active');
        $('.flr-inner ' + el.data('rel')).faseIn({speed: "slow"});
    }`

more about options http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/